# Does Gauss' law simplify even if charge density is dependent on angle?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

We know that with Gauss' law applied to a charged sphere simplifies due to the symmetry of the sphere and we can take $E$ outside of the integral, but what if  the charge density $ \rho$ depends on either $ \theta$ or $ \phi$ , is there still spherical symmetry or are we now forced to deal with the integral $ \int \vec E . d \vec a$ ?

Comment: No, by definition something is spherically symmetric only if it depends on $|r|$ only. There may be some other symmetry that you can utilise to simplify the integral, and the solution for the field may even turn out to be something nice by chance, but there is no obvious spherical symmetry cropping up.

Answer (score 1):

You are not looking for only *geometrical* symmetry but *field* symmetry. You can see this mathematically. With you requation:

$$\int \vec E \,. \,\mathrm d \vec A$$

You wish to take $\vec E$ out of the integral. This can mathematically *only* be done, if $\vec E$ is *constant* throughout the entire area that we are integrating over. If we know that the charge distribution is constant throughout, and we also know that the area is a sphere, then *geometrical* symmetry implies *field* symmetry of $\vec E$ at every point on this sphere.

If the charge distribution is not constant, then $\vec E$ will not be constant on this sphere. Then the geometrical symmetry does not translate to field symmetry. Then, mathematically, $\vec E$ cannot be taken out of the integral since it is not constant throughout the integration area.

Comment: +1, but note that calling $\vec{E}$ "constant" over the surface of a sphere is misleading since it does not have a constant direction over this surface.  It would be more accurate to say that we need to have $|\vec{E}|$ constant *and* $\vec{E} \parallel d\vec{A}$ everywhere over the sphere.